# Не подгружаются файлы js в приложении Android с использованием Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, angular, cordova

Проблема такова, что после сборки из файлов в android.apk через Cordova не подгружаются js файлы на телефоне, хотя обычные теги и css файл подгружается. 
И `<app-root></app-root>` пустой и ничего не выводит из-за этого.
Использую angular 9

Так выглядит index.html

```html
        <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data:">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <!--  <meta charset="utf-8">-->
  <title>MyLearnProjectTest</title>
  <!--<base href="/">-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.fc35f7314568fe1394fb.css"></head>
<body>
<h1>MYTEST!</h1>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="runtime-es5.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es5.9e286f6d9247438cbb02.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main-es2015.08d75225dbb1496c7d59.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main-es5.08d75225dbb1496c7d59.js" nomodule defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Файл - config.xml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>TestApp</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*"/>
<!--  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-navigation href="data:*" />-->
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Может из-за того, что ругаются на CORS, в xml файле прописывал и все равно не работает.
Это увидел в браузере. И точно не знаю, почему не работает на андроиде.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, уже не знаю, что сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел такой ответ, у меня на андроиде заработал.

Было `<base href="/">` -> `<base href="./">`
И также нужно переименовать `type="module"` -> `type="text/javascript"` для js файлов.
Если будут еще варианты - пишите.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]